# Can't run xRDP, terminates unexpectedly

Tags: 10.04, windows, rdp

I can't run xRDP out of the box in ubuntu 10.04. I run xrdp on a laptop and try to connect to it using Window RDP client. It connect to RDP which prompt for a type of connection I tried any of them but all can;t work it gives a connection error. I got the following in the log.

```
[20110410-18:57:51] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 5 started successfully
[20110410-18:57:51] [INFO ] granted TS access to user test
[20110410-18:57:51] [INFO ] starting Xrdp session...
[20110410-18:57:51] [INFO ] starting sessvc - xpid=7046 - wmpid=7045
[20110410-18:57:52] [INFO ] session 7044 - user test - terminated
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had problems the xRDP package for 10.4.  I downloaded an installed the package from 10.10 and it works well.   I also had problems with some of the VNC servers.  I am currently running vnc4server successfully.

See my setup for [Remote Desktops with VNC and RDP](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/remote-desktops-with-vnc-and-rdp/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed vnc4server (xvnc) and I use "sesman-Xvnc" as module. I am running ubuntu 10.10 however.

Note that xrdp has to connect to a VNC server, so you have to have a vnc server installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you grant appropriate permissions to the xrdp user that installation creates?

```bsh
sudo usermod -a -G ssl-cert xrdp
```

Installation creates a user. If that user lacks certificate permissions xrdp will not function. This is spelt out in just about every xrdp installation guide ever written.

This may or may not be *your* issue but it can cause the described behaviour. Put the user xrdp into the ssl-cert group with the above command. Don't forget to bounce the service.

The command in and of itself provides the following details:

- (sudo) admin privilege is required
- (usermod) you are setting user privileges
- (-a -G) you are adding the user to a group
- (ss-cert) the group to which you are adding
- (xrdp) the user you are adding
- The name "ssl-cert" is pretty self-explanatory

The only thing this doesn't tell you is *why* and I covered that in the first sentence. Why the service needs a restart I leave as an exercise for the student.